# SQL Query to check if a record does not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table which holds details of all Students currently enrolled in classes which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE studentInClass(
studentID int,
classID int,
FOREIGN KEY(studentID) references students(studentID),
foreign key(classID) references class(classID)
);
```

And another table which contains details of students who have paid for classes:

```
CREATE TABLE fees(
feesID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
StudentID INTEGER, 
AmountPaid INT, 
Date DATE, 
FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES students(StudentID));
```

What I want to do is check whether a student who is in a class has not paid for that class. I am struggling to write a SQL query which does so. I have tried multiple queries such as:

```
Select studentInClass.StudentID
from fees, studentInClass 
where fees.StudentID = studentInClass.StudentID;
```

But this returns no data. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that a fee is for a specific class? I don't see any reference to classes in the fee's table.

Comment: Agree with @stickybit. In case that you only care if a student has paid any amount of money, you can do it with a simple `LEFT JOIN` and then `WHERE fees.StudentID IS NULL` because if a student shows up in `studentInClass` but doesn't show up in `fees` will give `NULL` to the right table.

Answer (score 3):

You want `outer join` :

```
select s.StudentID, (case when f.AmountPaid is not null 
                          then 'Yes' 
                          else 'No' 
                     end) as Is_fees_paid
from studentInClass s left join
     fees f
     on f.StudentID = s.StudentID;
```

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select s.*
from studentInClass s
where not exists (
  select 1 from fees
  where studentid = s.studentid
)
```

with this you get all the rows from the table `studentInClass` for which there is not the studentid in the table `fees`.
It's not clear if you also need to check the date.

Answer (score 0):

check it please:

```
select studentInClass.StudentID
from studentInClass inner join fees ON fees.StudentID = studentInClass.StudentID
```